# Autofac: Register all MediatR handlers as inner classes of generic types

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control, autofac, mediatr

## Context

While trying to simplify our MediatR code, we have created generic Request/Response/Handler combinations for GetAll, GetSingle, etc.. functionalities. Below you can find the GetAll implementation

```
public class GetAll<T> where T : class
{
    public class Request : IRequest<Response>
    {
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public IQueryable<T> All { get; set; }
    }

    public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Request, Response>
    {
        private readonly IRepository<T> repository;

        public Handler(IRepository<T> repository)
        {
            this.repository = repository;
        }

        public Response Handle(Request message)
        {
            return new Response
            {
                All = repository.GetAll()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

## Problem

We can't seem to register all our RequestHandlers at once using Autofac.

We are able to register a single specific type of Handler in our Autofac Module using:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(GetAll<>.Handler)).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

But we would like to do this for **all** implementations of `IRequestHandler<,>` (and not just the GetAll one). We've tried this using the `AsClosedTypesOf` function as suggested in the documentation:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(GetAll<>.Request).Assembly)
              .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>));
```

or

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(GetAll<>.Request).Assembly)
              .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>))
              .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

But this yields following exception:

> **Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException:** 'The requested service `'MediatR.IRequestHandler<GetAll<T>.Request,GetAll<T>.Response>'` has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.'

What are we doing wrong (or forgetting) here?

Comment: Maybe you can use my structuremap implementation. Its far from perfect since I had to specify types (command<>, commandHandler<>, query<>, ...) but maybe you can start from there: https://gist.github.com/hudo/0e9fb466c3fac5a04aa1b77cc95490e5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to register them at once because, as you mentioned, you have to register each of them as generics. However, there's a way for you to avoid manually keeping a list of such handlers with a bit of reflection:

```cs
var genericRequestHandlers = typeof(GetAll<>).Assembly
    .ExportedTypes
    .Where(x => IsGenericRequestHandler(x))
    .ToArray();

foreach (var genericRequestHandler in genericRequestHandlers)
{
    builder
        .RegisterGeneric(genericRequestHandler)
        .AsImplementedInterfaces();
}

private static bool IsGenericRequestHandler(Type t)
{
    return
        t.IsGenericTypeDefinition &&
        t.GetInterfaces().Any(i =>
        {
            return
                i.IsGenericType &&
                i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IRequestHandler<,>);
        });
}
```

Here's an explanation of the checks done in `IsGenericRequestHandler`:

- is the type a generic type definition? in other words, can we construct generic types out of this type definition? `GetAll<T>.Handler` is since you can construct `GetAll<int>.Handler`, `GetAll<string>.Handler`, etc... out of it
- does the type implement an interface that is a generic type? `GetAll<T>.Handler` implements `IRequestHandler<GetAll<T>.Request, GetAll<T>.Response>`, which is a generic type
- finally, is the generic type definition of this interface `IRequestHandler<,>`? in our case, the generic type definition of `IRequestHandler<GetAll<T>.Request, GetAll<T>.Response>` is `IRequestHandler<,>` so the type matches the necessary criteria.

I hope this makes sense.